# How to compound Expressions of similar types?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions, linqkit

I have two expressions, of the same type:

```
Expression<Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>>> exprA, exprB;
```

I would like to combine these two expressions, so that semantically it comes out as

```
a(b(T))
```

But I can't find the right syntax, even with LinqKit.

<strike>var exprC = exprA.Invoke(exprB);</strike> // doesn't work

How do you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your types are truly `Expression`s, you want this:

```
var c = x => a.Compile()(b.Compile()(x));
```

Otherwise if they are `Func`tions:

```
var c = x => a(b(x));
```

is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you're trying to do, the order of this might be wrong (if so just switch the position of f1 and f2 on the 4th line).

```
Expression<Func<string, string>> f1 = (s) => "hello" + s;
Expression<Func<string, string>> f2 = (s) => s + s;
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "p1");
Expression<Func<string, string>> ffinal = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, string>>(Expression.Invoke(f1, Expression.Invoke(f2, parameter)), parameter);
Console.WriteLine(ffinal.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(ffinal.Compile()("123"));
```

when calling ffinal it takes to string passed in, calls f2 and the result of that gets passed into f1, so the printed string is `hello123123`

also of interest logging the expression to string gives you this

```
p1 => Invoke(s => ("hello" + s), Invoke(s => (s + s), p1))
```

Comment: it's worth noting that this is basically making this: `(p1) => f1(f2(p1))`, if you are worried about efficiency, you could get the body of each lambda function replace the parameters and compile it into this: `(p1) => "hello" + (p1 + p1)"` that could be more efficient but a bit more complicated than my one liner.